# Ember binding with dynamic computed alias

Tags: ember.js

I have a component that is provided each record ('data') of a model, along with 'meta' information that defines the attribute of the record to use, and renders it to a table. Within the component I'm trying to bind the underlying record attribute to each UI element {{tdVal}}:

```
tdVal : function(){

    return Ember.computed.alias('data.' + this.get('meta').get('field'));

}.property()
```

Unfortunately this just renders [object object] in the UI. For comparison the following renders all of the items correctly, but obviously does not bind:

```
tdVal : function(){

    return this.get('data').get(this.get('details').get('field'));

}.property()
```

Am I going about this in completely the wrong way? Any help would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

To add clarity, if I bind to a literal key instead of an attribute key derived from the meta information I still have exactly the same problem, so I don't think it's an issue with using a derived key:

```
tdVal : function(){

    return Ember.computed.alias('data.partner_id');

}.property()
```

**UPDATE**

If I set the binding against the component as an attribute rather than a function assigned to the attribute, then it works. Problem is I can't do this as the key for the alias needs to be derived and not a literal:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({    
    tdVal : Ember.computed.alias('data.partner_id')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second way looks right. It doesn't bind because you didn't provide the properties to bind to:

```
tdVal : function(key, value){

    var path = 'data.' + this.get('details.field');

    if (value)    
        this.set(path, value);

    return this.get(path);

}.property('data', 'details.field')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately the second way is not suitable as it is a computed property and I need a 2 way binding (alias). Also the second way won't work as you can't do things like: 

.property('data' + this.get('details.field'))

Comment: I changed the code in my answer to provide two-way binding. And for setting up an observer for calculated key you may use http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#method_addObserver

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate you taking the time to help. This solution works - good call. I have also added another solution to the Answer. I wonder which would be best?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this. I think the computed alias was failing when returned from a function due to timing issues. Instead I added it to init()

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

tagName : '',

init: function(){

    this._super();

    this.set('tdVal', Ember.computed.alias('data.' + this.get('details').get('field')));
}

});
```

This has done the trick, everything renders as it should and updates to the UI are reflected in the model and vice versa.